# How to do a Recursive SELECT with repetitives values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm using SQL Server, and I have a table with `ID` father and `ID` son, but more than one row of this case, because I have others columns in same table.

I'm trying to do a recursive `SELECT`, but my query is returning a lot of rows, because my PK is made up from three columns.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TABLE

CREATE TABLE #TABLE
(
    ID_ORIGIN VARCHAR(15), --pk
    ID_NEW VARCHAR(15), --pk
    NR_VALUE VARCHAR(3), --pk
    VLR_PRICE FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO #TABLE
VALUES
('1111111111', '2222222222', '001', 100),
('1111111111', '2222222222', '002', 120),
('1111111111', '2222222222', '003', 130),
('1111111111', '2222222222', '004', 140),

('2222222222', '3333333333', '001', 150),
('2222222222', '3333333333', '002', 160),
('2222222222', '3333333333', '003', 170),
('2222222222', '3333333333', '004', 180),

('3333333333', '4444444444', '001', 190),
('3333333333', '4444444444', '002', 200),
('3333333333', '4444444444', '003', 220),
('3333333333', '4444444444', '004', 230),

('4444444444', '5555555555', '001', 240),
('4444444444', '5555555555', '002', 250),
('4444444444', '5555555555', '003', 270),
('4444444444', '5555555555', '004', 280)

;WITH Niveis AS 
(
    --FIRST ONE
    SELECT ID_NEW, ID_ORIGIN, 0 AS Level
    FROM #TABLE
    WHERE ID_ORIGIN = '1111111111'

    UNION ALL

    --SON
    SELECT T1.ID_NEW, T1.ID_ORIGIN, Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM #TABLE T1
    INNER JOIN Niveis ON T1.ID_ORIGIN = Niveis.ID_NEW
)
SELECT ID_ORIGIN, ID_NEW, Level
FROM Niveis
ORDER BY ID_ORIGIN, ID_NEW
```

[image]

I know with I use a group by in last query will resolve, but, my cost of this query will not have a good performance, because in some cases I have too much connections, and my return will be like this (with no group by)

[image]

```
SELECT ID_ORIGIN, ID_NEW, Level
FROM Niveis
GROUP BY ID_ORIGIN, ID_NEW, Level
ORDER BY ID_ORIGIN, ID_NEW
```

What can I do to solve this problem without needing to use a `GROUP BY` at end?

Expected result:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use images fur data, use tabke markup

Comment: You can pregroup your table. Either by taking distinct id's into a temptable and work on that or by grouping inside your cte.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it with the row_number() function, something like this

```
select t.id_origin, t.id_new, 
       row_number() over (partition by t.rownumber order by t.id_origin, t.id_new) as level
from   ( select tbl.id_origin, tbl.id_new,
                row_number() over (partition by tbl.id_origin, tbl.id_new order by tbl.id_origin, tbl.id_new) as rownumber
         from   tbl
       ) t
where  t.rownumber = 1  
order by t.id_origin, t.id_new
```

See [this dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/isaf6RSF)

the result is

| id_origin | id_new | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111111 | 2222222222 | 1 |
| 2222222222 | 3333333333 | 2 |
| 3333333333 | 4444444444 | 3 |
| 4444444444 | 5555555555 | 4 |